# Moment.js: getting translated text for the terms "day", "hour", "second" and "minute"

Tags: javascript, internationalization, momentjs

Using moments.js, it is easily possible to set a language and then get various date strings and "calendar style" text translated to the desired language.

However I could not find a way to get a translation to the "date components" themselves. For example, I would want to sue something like:

```
moment.lang('en'); // set english
moment.dateComponent.hour() // yields "hour"
moment.dateComponent.hours() // yields "hours"
moment.dateComponent.day() // yields "day"
moment.dateComponent.days() // yields "days"
moment.lang('nl'); // set dutch
moment.dateComponent.hour() // yields "uur"
moment.dateComponent.hours() // yields "uur"
moment.dateComponent.day() // yields "dag"
moment.dateComponent.days() // yields "dagen"
```

Does anyone know of such a way?

Note: I rather avoid getting the translations by doing string splitting on other methods for which the purpose is not getting the date component translated name.

Comment: Did you find a way? I need to get the terms "today" and "tomorrow" out of moment.js, but I also don't want to "hack" my way through.

Comment: @MichaelB today: `moment().calendar().split(' ')[0]`, tomorrow: `moment().add(1, 'day').calendar().split(' ')[0]`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know moments.js so far, but if you have a look at the source code (See http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-langs.js), you will find you desired information.

So you can access some information directly

```
moment().lang('en')._lang._months --> ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
```

quite usefull ... but

```
moment().lang('en')._lang._relativeTime.hh --> "%d hours"
```

does not store the information atomar. Since the languages are differently and can not be build this way!

As you can see that this information is not accessible like you want. Use a translation javascript for your "words".

Comment: Thanks. And yup, I have seen the information exists in one way or another inside private members. But I rather avoid these kind of hacks as much as possible, this is why I have written a note in the question ("I rather avoid getting the translations by doing string splitting on other methods for which the purpose is not getting the date component translated name.").